# Imagem não aparece na tabela

Tags: html, angular, angular-6

Uso Angular 6 e bootstrap. Tenho uma tabela e fiz isso para exibir uma imagem:

```
........
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let operator of dataSource">
   <td>{{ operator.operatorId }}</td>
   <td>{{ operator.name }}</td>
   <td><img src="../../images/delete16.png" ng-click="deletar(operator)" /></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

e minha sequencia de pastas:
**src/app/images**
e o meu html está nessa sequência
**src/app/get/operators/arquivo.html**

Logo estou a dois níveis abaixo da pasta **images**, por isso o **../../**. Dentro da pasta tenho o delete16.png.

quando renderizo a imagem não aparece. Veja o screenshot abaixo, do que é mostrado no browser.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: a imagem tem que existir na pasta onde o código é publicado

Comment: @JorgeCosta, não entendi o que você falou. Como assim. Ela existe na pasta images e o que mais eu devo fazer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230473/how-to-serve-up-images-in-angular2

Comment: @JorgeCosta, resolveu o problema.

Comment: Tem como fazer isso via bootstrap sem a necessidade de importar imagens?